# How to get button name programatically xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

How can I get Button name programatcalliy. I have 3 buttons in axml file 
button1, button2, buttton3.

```
button1.Clicked += delegate {

    ButtonStyle(button2);
};
```

ButtonStyle method

```
void ButtonStyle(Button btn)
{
    var id = btn.Id;
    btn.BackgroundColor = Color.Blue;
    btn.CornerRadius = 1;
    btn.BorderColor = Color.Red;
}
```

Here `var id = btn.Id;`  want to get Name of button but getting something like GUID. How can I get button name. 
While debugging I can see it within `base` but unable to fetch

[image]

Comment: What is the actual requirement? I mean what you are planing to do with this name

Comment: When I click btn1, it should be selected with highlighted gh color, border, some txtColor etc. & other buttons should turn to like gray or look unseletected as doing in iPhone's Call-->'Recents' tab, while switching to Missed calls & all calls .

Comment: Well. but what is the role of getting name?

Comment: I was hoping that if I get button name, I'll make switch case & can make them easily selected & uncollected with limited code.

Comment: If you are looking for checkbox thing to select or deselect use this https://devlinduldulao.pro/how-to-create-checkboxes-in-xamarin-forms/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into Binding and Mvvm approaches when it comes to Xamarin forms. However from what you explained in comments and current approach I would add all buttons to the list and loop through each one of them so:

```
List<Button> buttons = new List<Button>();
buttons.Add(button1);
buttons.Add(button2);
buttons.Add(button3);

button1.Clicked += delegate {

    ButtonStyle(button1);
};
button2.Clicked += delegate {

    ButtonStyle(button2);
};
button3.Clicked += delegate {

    ButtonStyle(button3);
};

void ButtonStyle(Button btn)
{

    foreach (var button in buttons)
    {
        if (button.Id == btn.Id)
        {
            button.BackgroundColor = Color.Blue;
            button.CornerRadius = 1;
            button.BorderColor = Color.Red;
            button.TextColor = Color.White;
        }
        else
        {
            button.BackgroundColor = Color.White;
            button.CornerRadius = 1;
            button.BorderColor = Color.Gray;
            button.TextColor = Color.Blue;
        }
    }
}
```

Or Simply you can just disable button. That should make it go different color again. So inside the loop instead of settings all the properties just go:

```
button.IsEnabled = false;
```

And the one u want to have correct colors:

```
button.IsEnabled = true;
```

You can also add Styling with:

```
button.Style = YourStyle;
```

Comment: As you said that I should use MVVM for this task. is it possible in this case, Can you please just give a hint, how can I start for this task.

Comment: Did code i give you work btw?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm
This is documentation. You probably want to use some MVVM libraries to make things easier. I would personally recommend FreshMVVM. Google it, person who created that library made a nice Tutorial on youtube about it also.

Comment: Thank you for valuable suggestion & sorry for irresponsible comment but when people don't have idea about something it become difficult to start. :)

Comment: No worries :) Happy to help.